# Django redirect error 500 to 404 when language not found

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I noticed that, when a language is referred in settings.py without proper pages in the website, it generates 500 pages.

For exemple :

```
    LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('fr', gettext('French')),
    ('it', gettext('Italian')),
    ('es', gettext('Spanish')),
    ('de', gettext('German')),
    ('el', gettext('Greek')),
    ('tr', gettext('Turkish')),
    ('ja', gettext('Japanese')),
    ('pt', gettext('Portuguese')),
    ('ar', gettext('Arabic')),
)
```

So, on my website, `en` `fr` `es` `de` and `ja` are translated and present on the website. Others aren't.
Then, if you try to reach : example.org/el/whatever it's raising a 500 error.

I would like to have a 404 in order to let the user in the website.

Does anyone has a clue about this problem ? Or do I have to remove the languages from the settings ?

many thanks.

Edit : here is the report I have with this error :

```
 Internal Server Error: /it/blog/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/views.py", line 34,
 in _handle_no_page
    resolve('%s$' % request.path)
  File
 "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 494, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File
 "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 358, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<RegexURLResolver <module
 'autocomplete_light.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/autocomplete_light/urls.py'> (None:None) ^autocomplete/>],
 [<RegexURLResolver <module 'djangocms_contact.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/proj_website/app/djangocms_plugins/djangocms_contact/urls.py'> (None:None)
 ^api/contact_plugin/>], [<RegexURLResolver <module 'taggit_autosuggest_select2.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/taggit_autosuggest_select2/urls.py'>
 (None:None) ^taggit_autosuggest_select2/>], [<RegexURLPattern None
 ^sitemap\.xml$>], [<RegexURLPattern None ^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$>],
 [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None) ^it/>, <RegexURLPattern
 None ^share/>], [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None)
 ^it/>, <RegexURLResolver <module 'djangocms_job.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/proj_website/app/djangocms_plugins/djangocms_job/urls.py'> (None:None)
  ^api-job_plugin/>], [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list>
 (None:None) ^it/>, <RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (admin:admin)
 ^admin/>], [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None) ^it/>,
 <RegexURLResolver <module 'cms.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/urls.py'> (None:None) ^>, <RegexURLPattern pages-details-by-slug
 ^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$>], [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern
 list> (None:None) ^it/>, <RegexURLResolver <module 'cms.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/urls.py'> (None:None) ^>,
 <RegexURLPattern pages-root ^$>], [<RegexURLResolver <module 'rosetta.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rosetta/urls.py'> (None:None)
 ^rosetta/>]], 'path': 'it/blog/$'}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File
 "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/views.py", line
 118, in details
    return _handle_no_page(request, slug)
  File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/views.py", line 38,
 in _handle_no_page
    raise exc
django.http.response.Http404: {'tried': [[<RegexURLResolver <module
 'autocomplete_light.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/autocomplete_light/urls.py'> (None:None) ^autocomplete/>], [<RegexURLResolver
 <module 'djangocms_contact.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/proj_website/app/djangocms_plugins/djangocms_contact/urls.py'> (None:None) ^api/contact_plugin/>],
 [<RegexURLResolver <module 'taggit_autosuggest_select2.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/taggit_autosuggest_select2/urls.py'>
 (None:None) ^taggit_autosuggest_select2/>], [<RegexURLPattern None
 ^sitemap\.xml$>], [<RegexURLPattern None ^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$>],
 [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None) ^it/>, <RegexURLPattern None
 ^share/>], [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None)
 ^it/>, <RegexURLResolver <module 'djangocms_job.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/proj_website/app/djangocms_plugins/djangocms_job/urls.py'> (None:None)
 ^api-jo
 b_plugin/>], [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None)
 ^it/>, <RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (admin:admin) ^admin/>],
 [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list> (None:None) ^it/>,
 <RegexURLResolver <module 'cms.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/urls.py'> (None:None) ^>, <RegexURLPattern pages-details-by-slug
 ^(?P<slug>[0-9A-Za-z-_.//]+)/$>], [<LocaleRegexURLResolver <RegexURLPattern list>
 (None:None) ^it/>, <RegexURLResolver <module 'cms.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/urls.py'> (None:None) ^>, <RegexURLPattern
 pages-root ^$>], [<RegexURLResolver <module 'rosetta.urls' from
 '/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rosetta/urls.py'> (None:None) ^rosetta/>]],
 'path': '/it/blog/'}
```

And it continues like this (I have 2 more big paragraphes) starting with :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cms/views.py", line 34,
```

and :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File
 "/var/www/webapps/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 150, in get_response
    response = callback(request, **param_dict)
  File "/var/www/webapps/proj_website/app/proj/views.py", line 84, in
 custom_page_not_found
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: Ok my apologies. I wanted to add it as a comment for more clarity but stack doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that something goes wrong in your views.py.

So you need to do the following in your view that is getting problem:

```
from django.http import Http404

def your_view(request):
    try:
       code_that_must_work_but_can_fail="goes here"
    except Exception, e:
       raise Http404
```

So what we've doing here is just wrapping all of code within view in try: except: so if somethng will go wrong in try block it will move to except block and there is raise instruction which will return 404 page.
Please create 404.html and 500.html in your templates to have nice pages even with 500